# Related List Lookup Question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

OK I have searched and searched for a simple answer to this task:

I have multiple lists that are related. Example: Client, Spouse, Dependent, etc. All lists have a lookup that references the Client table. This works fine.

If I add all the lists to a display (multiple App Parts) and put them in tabs so the data is presented in a better way how can I if I click on say Spouse and click "Add New" - how can I force the Lookup field to auto populate with the Client name in the main tab?

We have thousands of clients and manually filling in this field is not practical and I am still barely learning how to script, I am assuming this will require scripting to work.

Are there are easy solutions or OOB solutions I can use for this?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how this is all mapped together. Can you please describe the mechanics of this tab display you mention?

Comment: Ok so I have used hillbilly tabs to tab the different web parts on the page. Each web part is a related custom list, example: Master Client (Tab 1), Related Spouse (Tab 2), Related Dependent (Tab 3), etc. What I would like to do is if I go to Tab 2 and click add auto fill in the lookup in that list to the Client Name from Tab 1